# How to target variant on Cell component Chakra

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I want to set the variant of a single Td/Tr/Th etc component in the same way that it is possible to set the variant of the Table component.

I have tired the following to no avail:

```
export const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Tr: {
      variants: {
        example: {
          background: 'red',
        },
      },
    }
  },
});
```

```
<Tr variant="example" />
```